# Setup different shipping costs per product category

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, categories, shipping

I have multiple to products in two different categories; shirts and mugs. I want different shippings costs for these categories.

Currently I have a shipping method (default) which is (apparently) applied on all products, no matter which category.

How can I setup a second shipping method and apply them as soon as somebody adds a product to their cart which has this category (mugs in my case, different shipping price than shirts)?

Comment: Consider adding weight on the mugs product type. Then have the shipping category cost more if it has more weights.

Comment: Good thinking, that did work, thanks!